# GRUB shows Windows boot loader even after deleting Windows partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

[image]

I have these partitions: `sda 10/11/12` are data storage partitions and `sda 7/8` are Linux partitions. I don't know what all other partitions do and whether it is safe to remove them. Whenever I restart my laptop it shows the Windows boot loader too even after applying the command `sudo update-grub`.

Please help me to remove Windows completely.

Comment: why don't you format all other partitions except sda 7,8,10,11,12. That must solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know what sda 1,2 are for

Comment: It's explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition).

Comment: my ubuntu will boot even after I delete sda 1,2,3? The link says  it contains bootloaders for all installed OS's.

Comment: Deleting `/boot/efi` will (most probably) cause boot problems for ubuntu but you can reinstall grub2 from live cd/usb to fix that  as explained [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).

Comment: Unless you understand what's on them, deleting or reformatting partitions is asking for trouble. In this case, GRUB is detecting the Windows boot loader on the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) -- `/dev/sda1` in this case. (Caveat: Some OEMs put the Windows boot loader elsewhere, and it might be on `/dev/sda2` on this system.) Deleting one file (`bootmgfw.efi`) on the ESP should remove it from GRUB's menu, after `update-grub` is run. cl-netbox's answer does a more thorough cleaning of unnecessary files with minimal risk of creating new problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to remove **every trace of Windows** ... follow these instructions :
Boot from an Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
On the Ubuntu Live desktop open a terminal and execute the following command :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt  
sudo dbus-launch nautilus
```

Navigate to the `mnt/EFI` folder and delete everything except the Ubuntu folder.
Then open the Trash folder and empty Trash. Close Nautilus and open GParted.
Delete the partition `/dev/sda2` and the partition `/dev/sda3` (see screenshot).

Boot the Ubuntu system ... open a terminal and execute : `sudo update-grub`
Now there shall be no Windows entry in the GRUB boot loader menu anymore.
Important : Do NOT delete `/dev/sda1`, it would cause an unbootable system.

Note : Although removing entries from the `mnt/EFI` folder can of course be done from within the terminal, I intentionally chose this method to make it most easy for you to achieve what you want.